# Error Parsing XML; not well formed (invalid token)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am encountering 3 errors :

Error:(8, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@mipmap/bg').

Error:(1) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I do not know how to resolve these issues, any ideas? :(

activity_main.xml -->

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@mipmap/bg"
android:clickable="true"
android:backgroundTintMode="screen">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ClassesOffered"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="#ff50617c"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="getMe"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/StaffButton"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="#ff50617c"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@mipmap/iklogo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Try putting the bg.png file into the mipmap folder. But beware that the mipmap folder is used for **launcher icons**. For any other graphics, use **drawable**, instead. https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/goodbye-launcher-drawables-hello-mipmaps/

Comment: `mipmap` should be use only for the launcher

Comment: Tried cleaning it, and I receive these errors now : 

Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/bg').

Error:(42, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@mipmap/iklogo').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Try to sync project again and make sure bg and iklogo files are exist inside your folders/.

Comment: Synced and made sure the files existed in the location specified, still same error...

Answer (score 0):

When such errors, I suggest you to always use the following approach: remove the part of the code and see if the error is still remains. For example in your case start with removing whole `<ImageView .... />` because of suspect `android:background="@mipmap/iklogo"`. To be completely sure - rebuild/clean project. If issue still here - remove next tag. If you find tag with error, now you refine your search and remove some param lines (for ex `android:background="@mipmap/iklogo"`). And you quickly find source of your issue.